# Do the Red Dot, Reflex, or ACOG sights work with Sleight of Hand Pro?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Sleight of Hand Pro makes you go into ADS faster. Does this perk still work with the sights (Red Dot, Reflex, and ACOG)?

Also, in general (i.e., without the perk) is it slower to aim down the sights when you have an optic attached versus iron sights?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. All three sights can benefit from SoH Pro. Sniper rifles are the only exception.

Without the sights (in seconds):

AR: 0.25
SMG: 0.2
LMG: 0.35
Sniper: 0.4

With ACOG sights, assault rifles go up to 0.35, the others stay the same.

[Source](http://denkirson.xanga.com/735016527/black-ops/) with charts..

Comment: Was this from your own testing or do you have a source for this? I'm just curious where you can find this kind of information in general.

Comment: you're right. Added my source.

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for something like this for awhile